# Stop second method execution based on if conditions in the first method

Tags: c#

I have a method that contains some if statements:

```
private void ValidateInputs()
        {
            if (txtBox_eventName.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid event name", "Action Required", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                txtBox_eventName.Focus();
                return;
            }

            if (nud_noOfGuests.Value < 10 || nud_noOfGuests.Value > 200)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter no of guests between 10 and 200", "Action Required", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }

            if (radBtn_primeRib.Checked == false && radBtn_chickenMarsala.Checked == false && radBtn_gardenLasagna.Checked == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please make an Entree choice", "Action Reuired", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }
        }
```

I have a second method that does some other stuff. I am calling both of these methods in my click event. I want to stop the program to execute second method if any of the if conditions in the first method is met.

The click event where I am calling both methods is:

```
private void btn_createEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ValidateInputs();            
            SetValues();

            calcCharges = new CateringEvent(eventName, noOfGuests, selectedEntre, barOption, wineOption);
            lbl_calcEntreCharges.Text = calcCharges.EntreCharge.ToString("C2");
            lbl_calcDrinkCharges.Text = calcCharges.DrinksCharge.ToString("C2");
            lbl_calcSurcharge.Text = calcCharges.Surcharge.ToString("C2");
            lbl_calcTotalCharges.Text = calcCharges.TotalCharge.ToString("C2");

            txtBox_eventName.Enabled = false;
            btn_createEvent.Enabled = false;
            btn_modifyEvent.Enabled = true;
        }
```

I want `SetValues()` to run only if none of the if conditions from `ValidateInputs()` work. How do I achieve that in this case?

Comment: Please show method which you call on click event. My guess is to not return void, but bool, then you could decide if second method should be called.

Comment: @Hostel Updated the description with click method.

Comment: ValidateInputs should return bool, then in click method you will put if statement. If ValidateInpute == false then you should return and not call the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply change return type of `ValidateInputs` method to bool.

```
private bool ValidateInputs()
{
    if (txtBox_eventName.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid event name", "Action Required", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        txtBox_eventName.Focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (nud_noOfGuests.Value < 10 || nud_noOfGuests.Value > 200)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter no of guests between 10 and 200", "Action Required", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return false;
    }

    if (radBtn_primeRib.Checked == false && radBtn_chickenMarsala.Checked == false && radBtn_gardenLasagna.Checked == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please make an Entree choice", "Action Reuired", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And then change your click method to:

```
if (ValidateInputs() == false) // or if(!ValidateInputs())
   return;
SetValues();
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your method to return a Boolean as true or false.

```
private bool ValidateInputs()
{
    if (txtBox_eventName.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid event name", "Action Required", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        txtBox_eventName.Focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (nud_noOfGuests.Value < 10 || nud_noOfGuests.Value > 200)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter no of guests between 10 and 200", "Action Required", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return false;
    }

    if (radBtn_primeRib.Checked == false && radBtn_chickenMarsala.Checked == false && radBtn_gardenLasagna.Checked == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please make an Entree choice", "Action Reuired",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then inside your click event check the first method's output.

```
if(ValidateInputs()){
        secondmethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **simplest** way for the code you posted is to have your `ValidateInputs` return a `bool`, that is, a boolean (`true` or `false`). Then in your `btn_createEvent_Click` method check for the returned value of `ValidateInputs` with an `if` conditional and decide to or not to call `SetValues`. The corrected code is as follows:

```
private bool ValidateInputs()
{
    if (txtBox_eventName.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid event name", "Action Required", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        txtBox_eventName.Focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (nud_noOfGuests.Value < 10 || nud_noOfGuests.Value > 200)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter no of guests between 10 and 200", "Action Required", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return false;
    }

    if (radBtn_primeRib.Checked == false && radBtn_chickenMarsala.Checked == false && radBtn_gardenLasagna.Checked == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please make an Entree choice", "Action Reuired",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void btn_createEvent_Click(object object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if(ValidateInputs()){
        secondmethod();
    }

    calcCharges = new CateringEvent(eventName, noOfGuests, selectedEntre, barOption, wineOption);
    lbl_calcEntreCharges.Text = calcCharges.EntreCharge.ToString("C2");
    lbl_calcDrinkCharges.Text = calcCharges.DrinksCharge.ToString("C2");
    lbl_calcSurcharge.Text = calcCharges.Surcharge.ToString("C2");
    lbl_calcTotalCharges.Text = calcCharges.TotalCharge.ToString("C2");

    txtBox_eventName.Enabled = false;
    btn_createEvent.Enabled = false;
    btn_modifyEvent.Enabled = true;
}
```